# Cannot set property src of null at HTMLDivElement.menuBtn.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Unable to access source image. On clicking the navigation button, I am still seeing the menu icon and not the close icon. Since, I am a beginner, please help.

```
<script>
    var menuBtn = document.getElementById("menuBtn")
    var SideNav = document.getElementById("sideNav")
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu")

    sideNav.style.right = "-250px";

    menuBtn.onclick = function(){
        if (sideNav.style.right== "-250px") {
            sideNav.style.right = "0";
            menu.src = "images/close.png";
        } else {
            sideNav.style.right = "-250px";
            menu.src = "images/menu.png";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `sideNav` and `SideNav` aren't the same thing. Case is important.

Comment: Still facing the same problem

Comment: That is a new question then.